# Set nested form group/control values in reactive forms

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a `Reactive Form` in my app and the structure is below:

```
this.bioForm = this._fb.group({
  firstName: [this.user.firstName, [Validators.required]],

  experience: this._fb.group({
    field0: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(500)]],
    field1: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(500)]],
    field2: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(500)]],
    field3: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(500)]],
    field4: ['', [Validators.maxLength(500)]],
    field5: ['', [Validators.maxLength(500)]]
  }),

  skills: this._fb.array([], Validators.required),
});
```

Within my browser `local storage` I have the following:

[image]

**What I have tried:**

```
 // Get Value from LOCAL STORAGE
 let localStorage_experience = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("experience")) || "";

 // Set nested form controls value
 this.bioForm.setValue({experience:{field0: localStorage_experience.field0 || ""}});
```

**I am trying to retrieve value from my local storage and set them against my nested form controls values.**

Comment: please post more "context-orientated" code. This is not enough to see what's going wrong

Comment: Whats the reason for a down vote? Its a straight forward question. How do you set nested form control values within an angular component. Not sure how else to ask this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `setControl` that replaces an existing formcontrol/formgroup/formarray:

```
this.bioForm.setControl('experience', this._fb.group(localStorage_experience));
```

**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cnrcyo?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

or then you can use `patchValue`:

```
this.bioForm.patchValue({experience: localStorage_experience});
```

If you want to use `setValue` you need to apply it on the nested formgroup, as `setValue` expects **all** values to be set.

```
this.bioForm.controls.experience.setValue(localStorage_experience);
```

Comment: Updated answer and gave a couple more options too, with `setValue` if you prefer that. At least you have to choose from :D

Comment: This is was perfect. Thank you. Im guessing the same could be used when using `_fb.array()`?

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you :) As for the formarray...yes, but only if it's of primitive type. Otherwise you need to iterate the array and create formgroups for your objects in the array.

Comment: It is a primitive type array but for some reason it won't set the values. and doesn't even give an error.

Comment: it should work... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iauxo1?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: its weird. I've tried exactly the same thing but no luck. Although my array is in local storage and Im getting it from local storage parsing it and then trying to set it.

Comment: Maybe stupid question, but have you checked that it is parsing correctly to an array?

Comment: Yeah just checked to make sure and it seems to parsing correctly. I console logged the parse array and its logging an array of strings. Im think Im making a stupid mistake somewhere but can't seem to find it.

Comment: You could try and take the demo and reproduce, and I'd be happy to take a look and see :)

Comment: hey mate while trying to reproduce the issue for you I figured it out. I was being an idiot and not updating the front-end. The array contains strings which represent checkbox values on the front end. And I was not updating the from-end to actually show the values. Thank you so much for all your help! =D

Comment: Great! I was almost gonna add in my previous comment that while you are trying to reproduce the issue you might find the issue yourself, and voila, it happened! :D Glad to be of help, you have a nice day and happy coding!